# Expectation value of a word with continuum of $3$ letters

Tags: probability

Taking the alphabet $a,b,c,..(27$ letters$)$ and assembeling word with length $1000$ find the expectation value of the numbers of he continuum with length $3$ (same latter $3$ times) for example: aaa,bbb,ccc,...

My try:

Let's the note $Z_i$ to be a random variable if there is a continuum of the same latter $Z_i-Z_{i+1}-Z_{i+2},\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,1\leq i\leq998$

$$Z=Z_1+Z_2+Z_3+...+Z_{998}\\ \mathbb{E}(Z)=\mathbb{E}(Z_1)+\mathbb{E}(Z_2)+\dots\mathbb{E}(Z_{998})=\mathbb{P}(Z_1=1)+\mathbb{P}(Z_2=1)+\dots+\mathbb{P}(Z_{998}=1)=   \frac{1}{27^3}998$$

But my answer is wrong

Comment: What are the 27 letters, please?

Comment: It dosen't really matter it could be $a,b,c,&,%,...$

Comment: There are 26 letters in the alphabet. Also, your answer relies on the assumption that the string ...aaaa... counts as two instances of having the same letter 3 times.

Comment: In my exersice there are 27 letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the calculation is that $$\mathbb{E}(Z_i)=\frac{1}{27^3}$$
This is the probability that you have a sequence of "aaa", rather than any three identical letters.  What you want instead is $$\mathbb{E}(Z_i)=\frac{1}{27^2}$$

Further explanation, as requested.  Say $Z_i^1$ measures the expectation of "aaa". Also $Z_i^2$ measures the expectation of "bbb".  Now these events are disjoint, so $$P(Z_i)=P(Z_i^1)+\cdots+P(Z_i^{27})$$

Comment: Yes, you are right, but why

Answer (score 1):

A group of $3$ letters consists of only one letter if the second and the third letter are equal to the first letter. The first letter does not matter. Therefore, the probability is $\frac{1}{27^2}$ instead of $\frac{1}{27^3}$